# count total database requests made for whole Laravel app

Tags: database, laravel, http-post

Every action within a Laravel app initiates via a route request, whether send or receive. I'd like to count the total number of times my Laravel app interacts with the database. if possible, some ways to also measure the average request time would be helpful.

I'm aware of `php artisan route:list` but I want a better alternative that I can present to somebody for decision making purpose.

Comment: Do you want to know the amount of interactions over a given time interval or more like a increasing integer in the database?

Comment: The time frame is not a constraint, I basically want to display how much resources my app uses as the database provider charges per interaction. I want to implement Redis and want to persuade them by giving them how many requests we're making and with Redis we can basically store data on which most of the app cycle depends on.

Comment: @laxit use [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) package or you can also try using [itsgoingd/clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork).

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to query events and take whatever action is best for you, such as logging or tracking metrics.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#listening-for-query-events

> If you would like to specify a closure that is invoked for each SQL query executed by your application, you may use the DB facade's `listen` method. This method can be useful for logging queries or debugging. You may register your query listener closure in the `boot` method of a service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        DB::listen(function ($query) {
            // $query->sql;
            // $query->bindings;
            // $query->time;
        });
    }
}
```